# angularjs: how to handle a popup with a directive so that data comes from controller model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-view

Suppose I have this tag in a template URL, into which HTML coming from the model is injected (HTML is basically <li> bullet points):

```
<div ng-bind-html="accident.description.impact"></div>
```

A portion of the model is as follows:

```
"cause": 

"<ul>\n\
    <li>\n\
    <div><span inline-popover \n\
        popover-html=\"Taper pour ouvrir la vue détaillée\" \n\
        popover-placement=\"bottom\" \n\
        popover-label=\"Larve de taupin\">Larve de taupin</span></div>\n\
    </li>\n\
    <li>Semences en cours de germination</li>\n\
</ul>",
```

And as you can see, some <li> contains tags that enables for opening a popup.

The issue I have, is that the span is cut off from his attributes, once injected in the partial.

Any idea?

Comment: You need to compile the partial before using it, Angular needs to understand that there are directives in the partial.  Check into `$compile` on the Angular site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is: the `ng-bind-html` does simply output the content of the variable. What you need here is a component, that `$compiles` the code, to make additional directives work.

```
<div ng-compile-html="accident.description.impact"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
directives.directive("ngCompileHtml", function ($http, $compile)
{
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
                "ngCompileHtml": "="            
        },
        link: function (scope, element)
        {
            var template = angular.element(scope.ngCompileHtml);
            $compile(template.contents())(scope);
            $(element).append(template);
        }
    };
});
```